# Can't make the menu bar adjusted

Tags: html, css

I've enlarged the menu space, but still when I add a new item to the menu, it becomes like on the screenshot (vertical). I'm very new in html css. How should I fix that, to make them next to another horizontal?

[image: The menu bar]

Comment: Can you provide us your code so we can help you ?

Answer (score 0):

To make list elements appear horizontally, you must add `li{ display:inline-block; }` to your css for the navigation. li elements are at default, block level elements which are displayed on a line for themselves, so to get them to behave and display beside each other, you must display the li elements as inline-block or inline. Inline-block would be better suited for your purposes for further styling of the li elements.

Comment: I added display:inline-block,but still the same

Comment: Can you paste your code for us to see then? Because that should definitely work, unless you have some conflicting css.